# Most accurate city level GeoIP tracking service?

Tags: geolocation, geoip

Can anyone provide a suggestion for a highly accurate GeoIP service that can locate a user down to the city?

Currently I am using MaxMind GeoLite but it is only 78% accurate. Even their premium is only 80%.

I was hoping to find something greater then 90% accurate at city look up based on IP.

Thanks.

Comment: We're using the Maxmind database as well and it seems to be OK - in Australia though where I guess there are less cities anyway than perhaps the US. How have you compared the premium vs open version of Maxmind?

Comment: If you are looking for highly accurate geolocation, html5 geolocation shall be the one. The drawback, it requires user permission to grant you the location information. For the IP to geolocation data, I don't think you can get >90% accuracy across world records.

Answer (score -1):

I've been looking into this myself, but since there are so many that I could only recommend you to take a look at this lengthy blog post:

https://medium.com/@ipdata_co/what-is-the-best-commercial-ip-geolocation-api-d8195cda7027

It's from one provider, but they compare other offers.